# Install ODAC in Windows 8 64 bit with Oracle Express 10g

Tags: .net, oracle, odac

I'm using windows 8 64bit with Visual Web Developer 2010 and Oracle Express 10g ,

i'm trying to access the Oracle Database using my VWD, and i was tried to installing ODAC with xcopy 64bit, but it doesn't work,

is there any advice or something that i must do for access Oracle Database ?

Thanks before, sorry if my pronounciation bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few year leave Oracle, finally i had chance to create a web application using Visual Studio and Oracle Database again. And I almost facing the same issue again as issue in this question. I've tried to Connect to Database Oracle from Visual Studio 2012 (in the past I still using VWD-Visual Web Developer) but the error cause is the same. One specific different things I use in my past and present project are the version of ASP .Net Framework I used. In the past project I use **ASP .Net 2**, and somehow the version of .Net Oracle Data Access I downloaded at that time is not compatible (which is version for .Net 3). As for my present project which is using ASP .Net 4.5, I accidentally got **Oracle Data Access for .Net 3**, and when everything installed on its place, the same error occurred. After a few googling and reading, I finally found out that each version of .Net Oracle Data Access is designed specifically for each version of .Net Framework.

As for now .Net Framework 4.5 and 4.6 are compatible with Oracle Data Access 12. 2c